# Why doesn't my alias work over ssh?

Tags: bash, ssh, alias

I have an alias defined in my `.bashrc`

```
alias l.='ls -d .* --color=auto'
```

It's very useful :) but it doesn't work via `ssh`:

```
$ ssh localhost l.
bash: l.: command not found
```

Why is that?

Comment: `.bashrc` is only read if the shell is interactive.

Comment: With your alias over ssh, there will probably be no color, where if you change your alias to `alias l.='ls -d .* --color'` then the colors appear.  Just thought I would add that.  At least I was experiencing that.

Comment: @Terrance I was wondering about that... I still get no colour (and no columns) although I get colour (and columns) as before after changing the alias (and doing `source .bashrc`)

Comment: ah ha!  I think I got it.  Try your alias as `alias l.='ls -dC .* --color'` where the `C` shows columns.

Comment: Aha I get columns! I know C is for columns but normally I get them without asking...  still no colour... (I'm not spelling it the British way in my alias, promise ;) ) @Terrance

Comment: What terminal application are you using?  I am doing my tests in xfce4-terminal.

Comment: I edited the answer to address the color issue.

Comment: @Terrance MATE terminal...

Comment: Is the color still not showing up with the answer Matei gave below?

Comment: @Terrance yes it does work (as I commented on the answer)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try:

```
ssh localhost -t bash -ci l.
```

Note:

- The alias should be in `~/.bashrc` on the remote server, not on your local machine.
- The `-i` option tells `bash` to run an interactive shell. Aliases are enabled by default only in interactive shells.
- The `-t` options tells `ssh` to allocate a pseudo-tty. Without this, `bash` emits a warning message when started in interactive mode. This also enables `ls` colors. Without it, you'd have to use `--color=always`, see `man ls`.
- There is another way to enable aliases, without setting the interactive flag, namely `shopt -s expand_aliases`. So you could try:

  ```
  ssh localhost 'bash -c "shopt -s expand_aliases; l."'
  ```

  However:

  - Your `.bashrc` might only define aliases if the shell sourcing it is interactive. In this example, the shell would not be interactive at that time.
  - If you try to define aliases on the same line, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501056/cant-get-expand-aliases-to-take-effect).

Comment: that works.... to your explanation, sure, but I am `ssh` ing to myself :)

Comment: I meant in general when using `ssh`. Yes, with `localhost` that's not a problem.

Comment: `ssh ... <cmd>` exits when `<cmd>` is done.  If you want to keep the shell around after `ls`, try `ssh localhost -t 'bash -ci "l.; exec bash"'`.

Comment: Aha I understand. Thanks a lot. I'm going to delete my comments :)