# aliases not getting expanded when run through SSH

Tags: bash, ssh, alias

so I have a alias for hadoop which I defined in bash_aliases which bashrc touches upon I guess.

```
alias hadoop=/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/bin/hadoop
```

Now the alias works fine when I directly try to run it. But when I try this

```
ssh aditya@localhost hadoop
```

I get the following error message

```
bash: hadoop: command not found
```

I tried the following too

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

But that didn't work. Could anyone help me out.

Update:

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/810098/why-doesnt-my-alias-work-over-ssh) question is different from mine, because the ssh command is not generated by me, so the solution to that question does not solve my question. The ssh command is generated and executed by a script inside a library I am using. I do not prefer to modify that script to change the command as I am not completely aware of how that script works.

Comment: See the linked duplicate. Basic answer is that aliases only work on local system. You have to define that alias on remote system to make it work there

Comment: I don't have a remote system. I am ssh into localhost!

Comment: Ah, I see. Hold on, I'll post an answer

Comment: Here it would probably make more sense to add `/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/bin` to `PATH`.

Comment: Why are you ssh'ing to your system in the first place ? Why not use just the regular terminal ?

Comment: I've added alternative approach to my answer. Please see it

Comment: In the duplicate question, the OP is also ssh-ing to localhost

Comment: Well,unfortunately I retracted my vote, so others will have to vote.

Comment: @Serg Voted as dupe

Answer (score 1):

From `man ssh`

> If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell.

That implies that shell will run your command as `sh -c`. That's first of all - this runs in `dash`, which is default shell and symlinked to `/bin/sh`. So your alias for `bash` won't work in the first place.

Second of all, `sh -c` is non-interactive shell. That means it won't source your `~/.bashrc` if you have defined alias there.

But main reason why your command does not work is because you run

```
alias hadoop=/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/bin/hadoop
```

in the *current shell* session. It is not exported, nor it is in `~/.bashrc` to be sourced to begin with

---

Here's an alternative.  Make alias in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias run_hadoop='ssh aditya@localhost /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/bin/hadoop'
```

That way it will be way easier , than defining alias for just command and failing over and over to run it. Alternatively , make a wrapper script `run_hadoop.sh` in your home directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/bin/hadoop
```

Make sure it is executable with `chmod +x run_hadoop.sh`. After that you can do

```
ssh aditya@localhost 'bash /home/user/run_hadoop.sh'
```

Comment: Hey, read the update I wrote on my question. Your solution does not work because of that.

Comment: @Aditya  Well, there's not really much  one can do about aliases. You *will* have to modify your ssh command to  source the `~/.bash_aliases`   , `ssh aditya@localhost 'bash -c "source ~/.bashg_aliases; hadoop"'`.  Sorry, but there's really no way without modifying.

Comment: Hadoop doesn't need to be an alias. I can make it whatever I want. I can try the path option too, but I am not sure how to do it. I tried path=$path:/usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/bin like he suggested but that didn't work. Someone in IRC told me to try functions but that didn't work either.

Comment: `PATH` has to be capital. If you are setting it in `~/.bashrc`, like i said, that won't work because it's non interactive shell. `PATH` is only sourced in interactive shells.